# How to create two columns PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, html-table

I am having the worst time trying to create this, it should be simple. I have an `$info` array that consists of `$person=>$personInfoArray` and I am trying to say, for the first six, do one column, for the next x amount, do another column.

What I have is:

```
$infoCounter = 0;
foreach($info as $person => $information){
    $infoCounter++;
    echo '<tr>';
    if($infoCounter <= 5){
        echo '<td>'.$person.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$information['Extension'].'</td>';
    }elseif($infoCounter > 5){
        echo '<td>'.$person.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$information['Extension'].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

I am essentially trying to create a table that looks like:

```
Name            Extension              Name               Extension
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Some one         54545                 Name               9785
Some One else    54212                 Something else     44121
```

But I am getting:

```
Name            Extension              Name               Extension
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Some one         54545                 
Name             9785
Some One else    54212 
Something else   44121
```

Thoughts? This should be ridiculously easy.

Comment: that doesnt help me at all. I am asking for an explanation on how to make this work

Comment: in a second Name <td> (in the same <tr>) put $info[$key+6] value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See that you are creating a `<tr>` for each person, try doing something like this:

```php
$infoCounter = 0;
foreach($info as $person => $information){
    if ($infoCounter % 2 == 0) {
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    echo '<td>'.$person.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$information['Extension'].'</td>';
    if ($infoCounter % 2 == 0) {
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $infoCounter++;
}
```

Check that `%` its the [modulus](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Answer (score 1):

You will always have "2" columns with this code. I think what you are after is this.

```
$counter = 0;
    foreach($info as $person => $information){
        if($counter == 0) echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>$person</td>";
        echo "<td>$information</td>";
        $counter += 2;
        if($counter == 4) {
            $counter = 0;
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
```

Keep in mind this is crude and off the top of my head. Not sure why you want 4 columns for 2 column information, other than formatting.